# Conflicting types for a struct

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef, function-declaration

I have a homework where i have a codebase that i cannot modify, and i have to make a struct that has to be filled with a function.
Here's the code, where the function fillDrivers() is from the codebase, the struct is made by me.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void fillDrivers(Driver[]);

typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int carNumber;
    bool rookie;
}Driver;

int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}

void fillDrivers(Driver arrayDrivers[]) {

    int i = 0;
    // Lewis Hamilton
    strcpy(arrayDrivers[i].name, "Lewis");
    strcpy(arrayDrivers[i].surname, "Hamilton");
    arrayDrivers[i].carNumber = 44;
    arrayDrivers[i].rookie = false;
    i++;

}
```

The original codebase has all the drivers in the grid, i left only the first one to reduce the size.
The problem is that this code gives me this error: **Conflicting types for 'fillDrivers'** at line 19.
If in the struct i add the square brackets at Driver, i get this error:
**Array has incomplete element type 'Driver' (aka 'struct (unnamed struct at C:\Users\paual\Desktop\Uni\Programmazione\Homeworks\Homework_3nuovo\main.c:7:9) []')**, this too at line 19.

What do i have to do?

Comment: Move the function prototype to after the struct definition.

Comment: Or declare the struct before the function and name the struct.  (eg `struct driver; void fillDriver(struct driver *); typedef struct driver { } Driver;`). Or, best of all, drop the stupid typedef completely.  typedef's are useful for clarifying function pointer definitions and a few other things; this is *not* an appropriate use of a typedef.

Comment: C files are generally parsed from top to bottom, like when reading a book. If the reader (the compiler) encounters something it has not read about before, it gets confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at first to declare the name Driver and only after that to use it in the function declaration

```
typedef struct{
    char name[20];
    char surname[20];
    int carNumber;
    bool rookie;
}Driver;

void fillDrivers(Driver[]);
```